# C# is there any better way to check if more than 2 properties in an object is not null

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to check if more than 2 properties in a object has value and return invalid string if so

Example :

```
Class Student
{
  string Name
  string Code
  string SNumber
}
```

Considering above code example , below scenarios can be written

```
if(studentObj.Name != null && studentObj.Code != null) 
   return "invalid";
if(studentObj.Name != null && studentObj.SNumber != null) 
   return "invalid";
if(studentObj.Code != null && studentObj.SNumber != null) 
   return "invalid";
```

Is there a way this can be simplified?

Thanks

Comment: define "better" - what problem do you have with your current solution?

Comment: Try counting : int count = 0; if(Name == null) count++;if(Code == null)count+++;if(SNumber == null)count++; if(count >1) return "invalid"';

Comment: [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) :D (not affiliated, but passionate client of)

Comment: You could possibly use reflection to see whether the count of properties in the object where value equals null > 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
typeof(Student).GetFields() // use GetProperties() if you have them, and not fields
        .Select(field => field.GetValue(studentObj) as string)
        .Count(value => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
```

Comment: Probably best to just use `.Where(field => field.FieldType == typeof(string))`

Comment: Not necessary in this case, since non-strings will just turn into nulls, and we are counting not-nulls.

Comment: "Probably best" because it means you don't retrieve field values unnecessarily

Answer (score 1):

You could actually count:

```
class Student
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Code {get; set;}
  public string SNumber {get; set;}
}

class StudentValidator
{
  public string Validate(Student student)
  {
     int nonZeroCount = 0;
     if( student.Name is object ) nonZeroCount++;
     // in C# 9: if( student.Name is not null )
     if( student.Code is object ) nonZeroCount++;
     if( student.SNumber is object ) nonZeroCount++;
     return (nonZeroCount > 2)? "invalid" : "valid";
  }
}
```

Mind that you might prefer to check either with

- [`string.IsNullOrEmtpty(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-5.0#System_String_IsNullOrEmpty_System_String_) or
- [`string.IsNullOrWhitespace(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-5.0#System_String_IsNullOrWhiteSpace_System_String_)

Comment: Thanks Fildor, actually that was a simple example I have given but there can be many properties inside student object

Comment: In that case, you may want to consider one of the reflection answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can optionally optimize the select statement, but as an example, I offer this option for discussion:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student{Name = "Mary",      Code = "1", SNumber = "001" },
                new Student{Name = "Sarah",     Code = "",  SNumber = "002" },
                new Student{Name = "",          Code = "3", SNumber = "003" },
                new Student{Name = "Katherine", Code = "4", SNumber = "004" },
                new Student{Name = "Eva",       Code = "",  SNumber = "" }
            };

            var listedProperty = from student in students
                                  select new List<string> { student.Name, student.Code, student.SNumber };

            listedProperty
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(l =>
                {
                    var nullPropertyCount = l.Count(i => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i));

                    if (nullPropertyCount <= 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", l.ToArray()));
                    }
                });

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
    }
```

Output result to the console:
[image]